# Is there a voltage difference between grounds of different areas?

Tags: ground

Say that I pull a 100m long conductor wire between 2 areas, will there be a difference in voltage?  E.g. will there be a flow of some current back and forth?

Reason I ask this is because I know that the voltage of ground is zero, but what I don't know if that's just a relative convention for a circuit in a given area, or is it also an absolute voltage even across the grounds of different areas.

Comment: Ground is zero by convention. Two different grounds are not necessarily the same voltage, especially if they're far apart.

Comment: Yes, this is a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between grounds which results in many problems to solve such as ground loops and interference. Especially when transmitting signals between distant modules which can be solved by using ground loop isolators.
This is also experienced on the same pcb at high frequencies where grounding is a crucial design issue.

Comment: Amazing sir..  Thanks.  Got specific simple examples of how ground changes even in the same PCB?  Like how frequency affects this?  Frequency of what?

Comment: Another question: is there any known experiment that proves that voltage changes across grounds of different areas?

Comment: @caveman when the signal frequency is too high the wavelength may become in the order of magnitude of the circuit on a pcb. In other words at two points of the same line on the pcb even if the resistance in between is null we can have different voltages at the same time. Think of an antenna...